# C++ templated alias of N-dimensional vector

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I want some simple wrapper for N-dimensional vectors like `vector<vector<vector<double>>>`, etc. More precisely, I would like to write in my code something like `NDvector<3,double>` instead of `vector<vector<vector<double>>>`. What would be the most elegant way to implement this? My idea is to write something like

```
template<size_t N, typename T>
using NDvector = vector<NDvector<N-1, T>>;

template<typename T>
using NDvector<1,T> = vector<T>;
```

However, this one doesn't compile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Type alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) can't be partial specialized;

> It is not possible to [partially](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization) or [explicitly specialize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) an alias template.

You can add a class template which could be partial specialized. e.g.

```
template<size_t N, typename T>
struct NDvector_S {
    using type = vector<typename NDvector_S<N-1, T>::type>;
};
template<typename T>
struct NDvector_S<1, T> {
    using type = vector<T>;
};

template<size_t N, typename T>
using NDvector = typename NDvector_S<N, T>::type;
```

then you can use it as

```
NDvector<3, double> v3d; // => std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>>
```

Comment: Perhaps, not as elegant as I would hope to see it in the ideal world, but works perfectly fine!